# get asp textbox from backend code vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

code

```
drOutA.Item("parameters") = dr.Item(1)
drOutA.Item("inputType") = " <asp:TextBox ID='LabelValue'  runat='server' Text='" & dr.Item(2) & "'></asp:TextBox>"
```

aspx page

```
<td><asp:Label ID="Labelpar" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("parameters")%>'></asp:Label></td>
<td><%# Eval("inputType")%></td>
```

ind this code `<%# Eval("parameters")%>` is displaying the text but `<%# Eval("inputType")%>` is not displaying anything which I assigned asp textbox

Comment: Why such strange requirement? Can't you place the textbox in markup?

Comment: @RahulSingh I want to use different input type(textbox, dropdown,...) for each parameters

Comment: Okay but still maintain them in your markup and set it's visibility based on the value rather than doing it like this.

Comment: good idea, I will try that. Thanks :)

Comment: If you absolutely want to ad them dynamically you could also look into using an asp placeholder.